# Create a global static variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, global-variables

Is there a way to create a global variable in SQL Server, in such a way that it persists even if the server is restarted, so I can use it in functions?

Example from what I need:

```
DECLARE @@DefaultValue bit
```

This variable should never be deleted unless I explicityl do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess this will work the best for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetDefaultPercent]()
RETURNS decimal(5,4)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1.0000
END
```

Comment: How is this variable?

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G: You can use it _variable-esque_, like in conditionals, even though it’s merely a work-around for a non-existing feature.

Comment: @dakab A constant then, which I guess could go part way to a solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can have a look at something like this

["Global variables" in SQL Server](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/04/23/60185.aspx)

Comment: Global variables are not persistent at all.

Comment: how would you use those global variables in a query?

Comment: This would be better as user-defined functions than stored procedures, particularly for use in a query, otherwise you have to add and assign a variable for each value used. Also, those prefixes are not a good idea: • https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix • https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem • https://github.com/red-gate/SQL-code-smells#naming • https://xkcd.com/645/

Answer (score 5):

Not a global variable.

There's chance you can define a global UDF like you can create a "system" stored proc (starts "sp" in master), but I've not tried it.

Note:

Even `DECLARE @@DefaultValue bit` is actually local:

`@` means local variable, identifier is `@DefaultValue`

It's not really global: try `SELECT @@DefaultValue` from 2 another query window

Answer (score 0):

I know is answered but just for fun :)

How about a table with 2 columns like:

```
GLB_VARIABLES:
GLB_VAR_NAME varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,
GLB_VAR_VALUE varchar(100)
```

Comment: Astander's answer links to an example of how to do this kind of thing robustly, and how to actually use them.